# How to assign hexadecimal values to arrays using switch or an if-else step at particular locations?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting, hex

I was working on a hobby project and it require me to assign hex values to an array based on certain hex function calls. However the array is not returned and simply freezes the program at execution.Looking for some insights.

I need to then take the returned unsigned char array and then move it to a second array free of NULL values. This I will use in my main program.

Thanks,
Aurelius

```
    //Function to get hex condition
    unsigned char set_lpx_var(char S0,char S1,char S2,char S3)
    { 
    unsigned char PIN;
    if((S0==0)&&(S1==0)&&(S2==0)&&(S3==0)) PIN = 0x00;               
    else if((S0==1)&&(S1==0)&&(S2==0)&&(S3==0)) PIN = 0x01;          
    else if((S0==0)&&(S1==1)&&(S2==0)&&(S3==0)) PIN = 0x02;          
    else if((S0==1)&&(S1==1)&&(S2==0)&&(S3==0)) PIN = 0x03;
    else if((S0==0)&&(S1==0)&&(S2==1)&&(S3==0)) PIN = 0x04;
    else if((S0==1)&&(S1==0)&&(S2==1)&&(S3==0)) PIN = 0x05;
    else if((S0==0)&&(S1==1)&&(S2==1)&&(S3==0)) PIN = 0x06;
    else if((S0==1)&&(S1==1)&&(S2==1)&&(S3==0)) PIN = 0x07; 
    else if((S0==0)&&(S1==0)&&(S2==0)&&(S3==1)) PIN = 0x08;
    else if((S0==1)&&(S1==0)&&(S2==0)&&(S3==1)) PIN = 0x09;
    else if((S0==0)&&(S1==1)&&(S2==0)&&(S3==1)) PIN = 0x0A;
    else if((S0==1)&&(S1==1)&&(S2==0)&&(S3==1)) PIN = 0x0B;
    else if((S0==0)&&(S1==0)&&(S2==1)&&(S3==1)) PIN = 0x0C;
    else if((S0==1)&&(S1==0)&&(S2==1)&&(S3==1)) PIN = 0x0D;
    else if((S0==0)&&(S1==1)&&(S2==1)&&(S3==1)) PIN = 0x0E;
    else if((S0==1)&&(S1==1)&&(S2==1)&&(S3==1)) PIN = 0x0F; 
    else PIN = 0x00;
    printf("\n Obtained hexa digit %u",(unsigned)PIN);
    return PIN;                                       
    }
```

Function to assign hex values to array

```
    unsigned char* command(unsigned char PIN,int sw,int size)
    { 
    unsigned char* x;
    x = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
    //select line assignment to array

    if(sw == 1)
    {
    if(PIN==0x00)
    {
        x[0]='0';
        x[1]='0';
        x[2]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0X01)
    {
        x[0]='1';
        x[1]='0';
        x[2]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x02)
    {
        x[0]='0';
        x[1]='1';
        x[2]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x03)
    {
        x[0]='1';
        x[1]='1';
        x[2]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x04)
    {
        x[0]='0';
        x[1]='0';
        x[2]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x05)
    {
        x[0]='1';
        x[1]='0';
        x[2]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x06)
    {
        x[0]='0';
        x[1]='1';
        x[2]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x07)
    {
        x[0]='1';
        x[1]='1';
        x[2]='1';
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %u",(unsigned)PIN);
    }
    //selection command
    return x;
    }

   else if(sw == 2)
    {
   if(PIN==0x00)
    {
        x[3]='0';
        x[4]='0';
        x[5]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0X01)
    {
        x[3]='1';
        x[4]='0';
        x[5]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x02)
    {
        x[3]='0';
        x[4]='1';
        x[5]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x03)
    {
        x[3]='1';
        x[4]='1';
        x[5]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x04)
    {
        x[3]='0';
        x[4]='0';
        x[5]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x05)
    {
        x[3]='1';
        x[4]='0';
        x[5]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x06)
    {
        x[3]='0';
        x[4]='1';
        x[5]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x07)
    {
        x[3]='1';
        x[4]='1';
        x[5]='1';
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %u",(unsigned)PIN);
    }
    //selection command
    return x;
    }

     else if(sw == 3)
    {
    if(PIN==0x00)
    {
        x[6]='0';
        x[7]='0';
        x[8]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0X01)
    {
        x[6]='1';
        x[7]='0';
        x[8]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x02)
    {
        x[6]='0';
        x[7]='1';
        x[8]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x03)
    {
        x[6]='1';
        x[7]='1';
        x[8]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x04)
    {
        x[6]='0';
        x[7]='0';
        x[8]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x05)
    {
        x[6]='1';
        x[7]='0';
        x[8]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x06)
    {
        x[6]='0';
        x[7]='1';
        x[8]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x07)
    {
        x[6]='1';
        x[7]='1';
        x[8]='1';
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %u",(unsigned)PIN);
    }
    //selection command
    return x;
    }

    else if(sw == 4)
    {
    if(PIN==0x00)
    {
        x[9]='0';
        x[10]='0';
        x[11]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0X01)
    {
        x[9]='1';
        x[10]='0';
        x[11]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x02)
    {
        x[9]='0';
        x[10]='1';
        x[11]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x03)
    {
        x[9]='1';
        x[10]='1';
        x[11]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x04)
    {
        x[9]='0';
        x[10]='0';
        x[11]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x05)
    {
        x[9]='1';
        x[10]='0';
        x[11]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x06)
    {
        x[9]='0';
        x[10]='1';
        x[11]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x07)
    {
        x[9]='1';
        x[10]='1';
        x[11]='1';
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %u",(unsigned)PIN);
    }
    //selection command
    return x;
    }

    else if(sw == 5)
    {
    if(PIN==0x00)
    {
        x[12]='0';
        x[13]='0';
        x[14]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0X01)
    {
        x[12]='1';
        x[13]='0';
        x[14]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x02)
    {
        x[12]='0';
        x[13]='1';
        x[14]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x03)
    {
        x[12]='1';
        x[13]='1';
        x[14]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x04)
    {
        x[12]='0';
        x[13]='0';
        x[14]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x05)
    {
        x[12]='1';
        x[13]='0';
        x[14]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x06)
    {
        x[12]='0';
        x[13]='1';
        x[14]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x07)
    {
        x[12]='1';
        x[13]='1';
        x[14]='1';
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %u",(unsigned)PIN);
    }
    //selection command
    return x;
    }

     else if(sw == 6)
    {
    if(PIN==0x00)
    {
        x[15]='0';
        x[16]='0';
        x[17]='0';
        x[18]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x01)
    {
        x[15]='1';
        x[16]='0';
        x[17]='0';
        x[18]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x02)
    {
        x[15]='0';
        x[16]='1';
        x[17]='0';
        x[18]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x03)
    {
        x[15]='1';
        x[16]='1';
        x[17]='0';
        x[18]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x04)
    {
        x[15]='0';
        x[16]='0';
        x[17]='1';
        x[18]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x05)
    {
        x[15]='1';
        x[16]='0';
        x[17]='1';
        x[18]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x06)
    {
        x[15]='0';
        x[16]='1';
        x[17]='1';
        x[18]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x07)
    {
        x[15]='1';
        x[16]='1';
        x[17]='1';
        x[18]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x08)
    {
        x[15]='0';
        x[16]='0';
        x[17]='0';
        x[18]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x09)
    {
        x[15]='1';
        x[16]='0';
        x[17]='0';
        x[18]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x0A)
    {
        x[15]='0';
        x[16]='1';
        x[17]='0';
        x[18]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x0B)
    {
        x[15]='1';
        x[16]='1';
        x[17]='0';
        x[18]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x0C)
    {
        x[15]='0';
        x[16]='0';
        x[17]='1';
        x[18]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x0D)
    {
        x[15]='1';
        x[16]='0';
        x[17]='1';
        x[18]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x0E)
    {
        x[15]='0';
        x[16]='1';
        x[17]='1';
        x[18]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x0F)
    {
        x[15]='1';
        x[16]='1';
        x[17]='1';
        x[18]='1';
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %u",(unsigned)PIN);
    }
    return x;
    }

    else if(sw == 7)
    {
    if(PIN==0x00)
    {
        x[19]='0';
        x[20]='0';
        x[21]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0X01)
    {
        x[19]='1';
        x[20]='0';
        x[21]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x02)
    {
        x[19]='0';
        x[20]='1';
        x[21]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x03)
    {
        x[19]='1';
        x[20]='1';
        x[21]='0';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x04)
    {
        x[19]='0';
        x[20]='0';
        x[21]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x05)
    {
        x[19]='1';
        x[20]='0';
        x[21]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x06)
    {
        x[19]='0';
        x[20]='1';
        x[21]='1';
    }
    else if(PIN==0x07)
    {
        x[19]='1';
        x[20]='1';
        x[21]='1';
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %u",(unsigned)PIN);
    }
    //selection command
    return x;
    }

    }
```

Main function

```
    int main()
    {
    int sw = 1,i,size=22;
    char S3=0,S2=1,S1=0,S0=1;
    unsigned char PIN;
    PIN=set_lpx_var(S0,S1,S2,S3);
    unsigned char *x;
    unsigned char *d;
    x=command(PIN,sw,size);//sw = 1
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if  (x[i]!='\0')
    {
    d[i]=x[i];
    }
    }
    sw = 2;
    S3=0,S2=1,S1=1,S0=1;
    PIN=set_lpx_var(S0,S1,S2,S3);
    x=command(PIN,sw,size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if  (x[i]!='\0')
    {
    d[i]=x[i];
    }
    }
    sw = 3;
    S3=0,S2=1,S1=0,S0=0;
    PIN=set_lpx_var(S0,S1,S2,S3);
    x=command(PIN,sw,size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if  (x[i]!='\0')
    {
    d[i]=x[i];
    }
    }
    sw = 4;
    S3=0,S2=0,S1=1,S0=1;
    PIN=set_lpx_var(S0,S1,S2,S3);
    x=command(PIN,sw,size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if  (x[i]!='\0')
    {
    d[i]=x[i];
    }
    }
    sw = 5;
    S3=0,S2=1,S1=1,S0=0;
    PIN=set_lpx_var(S0,S1,S2,S3);
    x=command(PIN,sw,size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if  (x[i]!='\0')
    {
    d[i]=x[i];
    }
    }
    sw = 6;
    S3=1,S2=1,S1=1,S0=0;
    PIN=set_lpx_var(S0,S1,S2,S3);
    x=command(PIN,sw,size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if  (x[i]!='\0')
    {
    d[i]=x[i];
    }
    }
    sw = 7;
    S3=0,S2=1,S1=1,S0=0;
    PIN=set_lpx_var(S0,S1,S2,S3);
    x=command(PIN,sw,size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if  (x[i]!='\0')
    {
    d[i]=x[i];
    }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
   {
   printf("Value at %i is %c",i,d[i]);
   }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Please format your code with proper indenting when posting a question.  Your code is very difficult to read.  Also it's probably better to put the main and global functions in one code block so that someone willing to help you can more easily copy and paste into a project and compile it.  Are you using a debugger?  If so how far did you get before the program started misbehaving?

Comment: I'm sorry for the mess really since I  got the code cut to size as the 8 space rule. Totally missed the code block icon. The trouble begins after you get the PIN hexadecimal value. Once the command function starts the screen just freezes up. I think it's a loose pointer somewhere but I can't be too sure. Would really appreciate a fresh pair of eyes on this thing.

Comment: Create a table of `PIN` values vs. `S0`, `S1`, `S2` and `S3` values.  You'll see a pattern or make a Karnough map to reduce it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to optimize you first function while reducing the possibility for errors:

```
//Function to get hex condition
unsigned char set_lpx_var(char s0, char s1, char s2, char s3)
{ 
   unsigned char result = (unsigned char)(((s3 != 0) << 3) + ((s2 != 0) << 2) 
                                        + ((s1 != 0) << 1) + (s0 != 0));
   printf("\n Obtained hexa digit %u", result);
   return result;
}
```

Function #2:

```
unsigned char* command(unsigned char PIN,int sw,int size)
{ 
  unsigned char* x;
  size_t offset = sw - 1;

  if (PIN & 0x08)  // hard to know from your code what to do in case 
                   // of error here. 
  {
     printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %u", PIN);
     return NULL;
  }

  if (size < 22 || (sw < 1 || 7 < sw))  // avoid out-of-bounds errors
  {
     printf("\n Invalid buffer size %d", size);
     return NULL;
  }
  x = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);     // why not new ? 
                                        // why not passing an array for result?
  if (!x)
      return NULL;
  memset(x, 0, size);    // dynamic memory needs to be initialized.

  //select line assignment to array

  size_t offset = sw - 1;

  x[offset + 0] = (PIN & 0x01) ? '1' : '0';
  x[offset + 1] = (PIN & 0x02) ? '1' : '0';
  x[offset + 2] = (PIN & 0x04) ? '1' : '0';
  return x;
}
```

As for main(), you do not check for allocation errors in return value from command(), you leak every single buffer returned by command(), and you assign values into d, which is an uninitialized pointer, this very likely generates a segmentation fault.

Comment: The new not being used is because I'm using Keil and  the if else nightmare is because of my weak pointer skills. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char *d;  // <-- d is an uninitialized pointer
x=command(PIN,sw,size);//sw = 1, ****x is assigned a block of memory within command so that's good****
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if  (x[i]!='\0')
    {
        d[i]=x[i];   // ****<-- where did you assign d to a block of memory?****
    }
}
```

**The most obvious issue I see is the assignment to the uninitialized pointer d.**  You need to allocate a block of memory for that.  There could be other problems in the program too which you'll need to debug in order to find.

Comment: Missed that right off the bat! I must be getting sleepy. The code now returns a full array of 0 and 1 along with the some garbage values like y and a smiley.